# winforms datagridview sorting using LINQ

Tags: winforms, linq, sorting, datagridview

Im using Linq...more specifically, [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com). anyway the following is an example of a query I have bound to a datagridview (winforms):

```
    public static List<Task> GetUserTasks( Guid userID ) {
        using (myDataContext ctx = new myDataContext()) {
            try {
                return ctx.Manager.Task.GetByUserID( userID ).ToList();
            } catch (Exception) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my UI, I have the following setup to bind:

```
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = DUtasks.GetUserTasks( User.Current.UserID );
        dgvTasks.DataSource = bs;
```

It works, but no sorting is possible.  I tried "AsEnumerable()" instead of "ToList()"  but that for some reason, throws an "objection reference" error.   Any ideas as to how I can proceed on this front?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, problem sorted!!! :)

found the following link: [SortableBindingList...](http://www.tech.windowsapplication1.com/content/sortable-binding-list-custom-data-objects) (my comment is at the bottom with converted C# working code).

Now all my query methods that return List<(ENTITY)> simply get used like this:

```
        SortableBindingList<Task> sortedTasks = new SortableBindingList<Task>( DUtasks.GetUserTasks( User.Current.UserID ) );
        dgvTasks.DataSource = sortedTasks;
        dgvTasks.Sort( colTaskDue, ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning an IOrderedEnumerable?  Not sure if it will help but that is designed to handle ordered LINQ results.

Comment: HI robber.  No unfortunately that does not work.  I already have tried an "orderby" appended to the query with no result.  I got the sort property in each column set to automatic (oh, btw, I hjave chosen not to autogenerate columns, if that makes a diff.), so I know that as soon as I have it right the SortGlyph is supposed to appear, right?

Answer (score 0):

use only MySortableBindingList class in this page Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-

then

var yourLinqList = ...;

MySortableBindingList sortList = new MySortableBindingList(yourLinqList);

dataGridView1.DataSource = sortList;

then your dataGridView must be sort when cell header click.